# Sending audio wireless from microphone to Android phone

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, android-audiorecord

I would need to retrieve data from wireless microphone couple of meters away from my Android phone and listen to it on my 3.5mm wired headset while recording audio to file. This should not be done during phone conversation.

At first I connected 3.5mm wired microphone to blue-tooth transmitter (bt music blue-tooth transmitter to be exact) and tried to configure my phone as same as blue-tooth speaker would be connected. Unfortunately, using Android phone as A2DP sink is not possible without customizing Android OS.

I tried following apps with blue-tooth headset but without success: Parrot, PlaybackMic, True Recorder, Lesser AudioSwitch, etc. I can record voice from blue-tooth headset microphone but cannot play it during the recording time.

In summary, is it possible to receive audio from blue-tooth headset microphone and route it to 3.5mm output while saving it to file?

If you have suggestions on how this can be achieved, I would like to hear it.